# C++ recursive function with switch() returns bad data

Tags: c++, function, recursion, cin, flush

I'm working on a project which requires some menus to be displayed some of them have sub-menus. So far i have created a function which returns the character that the user has selected, the problem is that after a couple and more back and forth between menus the return value is garbage, it has to do with the `cin` been flushed but i just can't find the "spot" that is has to be cleared...
I have tried `cin.clear();` on various places with mixed results what i'm missing?

Output:
[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>
#include <istream>
using namespace std;

char Menu() {
    char ch;
    //ch = NULL;
    //cin.clear();
    cout << "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << endl;
    cout << "+               MAIN MENU                  +" << endl;
    cout << "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << endl;
    cout << "| 1. Enter a new contract.                 |" << endl;
    cout << "| 2. Cancel an active conract.             |" << endl;
    cout << "| 3. Edit a cotract.                       |" << endl;
    cout << "| 0. Exit                                  |" << endl;
    cout << "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << endl;
    cin  >> ch; 

    switch (ch) {
        //cin.clear();
        case '1':
            return ch;
            break;
        case '2':
            return ch;
            break;
        case '3':
            //cin.clear();
             cout << "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << endl;
             cout << "+                -== Edit a cotract ==-                  +" << endl;
             cout << "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << endl;
             cout << " What would like to edit?                                |" << endl;
             cout << " a) Cover amount.                                        |" << endl;
             cout << " b) Add a family memeber.(Applyes to Health insurances)  |" << endl;
             cout << " 0. Return                                               |" << endl;
             cout << "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << endl; 
             cin  >> ch;
             if(ch == '0') {       
                 //cin.clear();     
                 Menu();
             } else if((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'b')) {
                 return ch;
             } else {
                 cout << "Wrong input ! ! !" << endl;
                 Menu();
                 return ch;
            }
            break;
        case '0':
            cout << "Exiting bye!" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong input ! ! !" << endl;
            Menu();
            break;
    }         
}

int main() {
    char choise;
    choise = Menu();
    cout << "selected: " << choise << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]*

Comment: Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 no wanring's at all

Comment: @Peter Then you do not pass `-Wall` on your command line to GCC. You should in fact pass `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: Making this function recursive is pointless and a bad idea. That's because calling Menu() doesn't simply jump to the start (like a *cough* goto would), but it adds a new function call to the stack. When the user selects 0 there, the old function call resumes and exits the function without a return value, thus delivering garbage.

Comment: @ammoQ i didn't know that, i thought i would get away with recursion...

Answer (score 2):

```
        default:
               cout << "Wrong input ! ! !" << endl;
               Menu();
               break;
```

You called another `Menu()` to fetch input, but didn't return its return value to caller `main()`.

Change it into `return Menu();`.

Comment: that actually worked i put in both return statments to 'return Main()' but after some back and forth seems to "loosing it" again